# Python requests from window.__STATE__

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to extract the location from this url (https://www.mapmyrun.com/workout/6292652533), but it seems that the returned information is different from if open that url in browser.

My simple code is

```
response = requests.get("https://www.mapmyrun.com/workout/6292652533")
document = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
document
```

Can someone explain me why? My only guess is this information is in **window.__STATE__** and Im not sure how to deal with it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What would you expect? You're not doing anything with the `document` object.

Comment: Thanks @baduker, I want to extract the "location" from that page. In that specific page, it is Exeter, United Kingdom.

Answer (score 2):

All the data about the workout (route, time, heartrate, location etc.) come from `API` endpoints.

Here's how to get the location:

**Note:** *You need to map the country name as it comes as `gb`.*

```py
import requests

country_mapping = {"gb": "United Kingdom"}
data = requests.get("https://www.mapmyrun.com/internal/route/4785611572").json()
print(data["city"], country_mapping[data["country"]])
```

Output:

```
Exeter United Kingdom
```

Comment: Thank you very much @baduker - I was thinking I could get the plain html instead of json. But this solution is even better.

Comment: Just realize, the url is different. How did you get https://www.mapmyrun.com/internal/route/4785611572 that associated with the exercise in https://www.mapmyrun.com/workout/6292652533?